# Selenium (web driver) - can't click on the right edge of split button (see link for the picture)

Tags: javascript, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I needs your's help on clicking on the right edge of split button (see link for the buttons and Html code)

In the Screen we have 2 buttons and I want to click on the status button(second button) in his right Edge.

The problem + the Html code:

http://tinypic.com/r/2nbejvp/8

I tried the code below (didn't work)..

option 1:

```
SeleniumApi.driver.findElement(By.xpth("//*[@id='ext-gen51']"));
or
SeleniumApi.driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen51));
```

option 2:

```
 WebElement ele = SeleniumApi.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen51']"));
 Actions build = new Actions(SeleniumApi.driver);  
 build.moveToElement(ele, (buttonwidth/2)+6, 0).click().build().perform();
```

option 3:

```
 WebElement first = SeleniumApi.driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen51"));
 first.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

option 4:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumApi.driver,30);
By findBy = By.cssSelector("tbody.x-btn-icon-small-left td.x-btn-mr");
WebElement element =    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(findBy));
element.click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumApi.driver,30);
By findBy = By.cssSelector("tbody.x-btn-icon-small-left em.x-btn-split");
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(findBy));
element.click();
```

option 5:

```
WebElement ele = SeleniumApi.driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen51"));
ele.click();
Actions build = new Actions(SeleniumApi.driver);  
build.moveToElement(ele, ele.getSize().getWidth()/2-5, 0).click().perform();
```

notes:

the page was genrate with extJS framework

I have 2 split buttons and i want to click on the second one.

Comment: I am looking at the page source of the URL you provided, and there is no indication of any `ext-gen88` whatsoever. Can you be a little more specific about the exact element that you are trying to click on?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. i am talking about "ext-gen51"(edit my question) or any other option to click on the right small arrow. if i will click on the Status button noting will happen. when i am clicking on the arrow a menu is open. i want to click on the arrow using selenium.

Comment: Can't find `ext-gen51` either. Is it in `http://i62.tinypic.com/2z8pzmc.png`, or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi , thanks for your effort. i upload the html code (in the new link - the code is below)

Comment: It is not clear from your question, what problem exactly you're experiencing. Is it a runtime exception? Or are you simply not getting anything after the click? Are you trying to click only one element, or three different elements, one at a time? It would be best if you simply publish the URL of the web-page that you are trying to control, and indicate which element or elements you want to click on.

Comment: Hi, i am not getting anything after the click. i am trying to click only one element (button right section). regarding the URL - i can't publish because it's inner URL. Thanks anyway for your effort :) i really appreciate it.

Comment: Well, `driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen51)).click()` should work, but I guess that you've tried it already, so the only help I can suggest is that you provide the URL and I'll try it myself...

Comment: I attached new link with more details

Answer (score 0):

The first option won't work, `findElement(By.id("//*[@id='ext-gen88']"))`,as you can see `//*[@id='ext-gen88']` is an `xpath` not an `id`. You should probably not worry about xpath or cssSelectors when an id is provided, id is the better and simpler way to reach any element.

so the below code would work,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen88"));
element.click();
```

or you can wait for the element to appear with [explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp),

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ext-gen88")));
element.click();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.(it was my mistake - i mean id).             I tried your both options that you gave,  but is doesn't work. any other ideas?

Comment: I don't get any error, the arrow isn't clicked and the code continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your DOM ids, it seems that your site uses extJS framework. As far as I know extJS generates random ids. Therefore ids that you see before can be different the next time you visit the DOM. Are you sure ids are constant?

For clicking on the right arrow button, I think you need to do below,

**Updated**
Unfortunately your DOM is little tricky and you should ask your developers to provide hooks to find elements easily. Here is quick and dirty solution, however functional. Give it a try.

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    By findBy = By.cssSelector("tbody.x-btn-icon-small-left em.x-btn-split");
    List<WebElement> elements=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(findBy));
    if(elements.size()==2) {
        WebElement element = elements.get(1); //if you want to click first buttons arrow, replace 1 with 0.
        element.click();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. you are right we are using extJS framework. Regarding to your answer, I have another split button on the same page.and this split button is before the one i want to click on.so your code are clicking on the first button and not on the one i need. i can't use the "ext-gen51" or any other idea?

Comment: You need to provide more HTML so that we can help. Based on the images you posted, I updated the selector. Can you try again?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort, The problem + the Html code is in the new link (I try to separate it to 3 links but i don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Hi, i was trying now (your updated answer). Thanks for the effort. It’s open split button - but not the "Status" button. i have 2 Split button on my screen. And I want to open the second button (right edge). And the code is opening other button (button1 -can be open on every click(not specific on the right edage) button2 -can open only when we click on it right edge).

Comment: Can you post image or html around the second button that you want to click?

Comment: Hi, i posted it in the new link. it's below the button image. do you need any thing else?

Comment: I am still not clear. Do you want to click on the button with "Status" or the "arrow" next to it? Are you saying there are two "Status" buttons and you want to click one of them? If so, please post html of both such elements so that we can filter the one you want to click

Comment: I attached new link with more details. i think it will be more clear now.

Comment: can you check now? with the new link.

Comment: .Hi, Thanks a lot for your effort! I really appreciate it! 
Unfortunately  it still doesn't work. your code is clicking on the "stauts" button, but probably not on the right edge of it.
manually when i am clicking on the right edge the menu is open (the yellow section in my link).
when I clicking  manually on the middle of the button nothing is happen (only when i click on  the right edge).
i know that you help me a lot, is there any other idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48518/discussion-between-nilesh-and-shay12)

Answer (score 0):

`SeleniumApi.driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen51));` this will get you the element right next to the edge, you don't want that element. From what I can see, you can get the table, then get the row and from the row get the table data you are interested. Use `driver.findElement(By.something)` to get the table, then call on the WebElement returned `table.findElement(By.xpath("tbody"))` -> `tbody.findElelements(By.xpath("tr")).get(1)`. With this you should have the second row as a WebElement. All that is left is to repeat the process and get from it the td element you are interested in.

 Or in one ugly line of code `driver.findElement(By.xpath("pathToTable")).findElement(By.xpath("tbody")).findElements(By.xpath("tr")).get(1).findElements(By.xpath("td")).get(2)` But for the love of God, do not use this! To recap, you get the table, the table body, the 2nd row and the 3rd  td from that row

Comment: Hi, i didn't understand on which table we are talking and how i can take it? can you explain me more?

Comment: @shay12 look at your pictures... you have a `<tbody>` some `<tr>` and `<td>` that means you have a table. just look in the css and you will see it

Comment: What i need to search on the CSS (i am not familiar with CSS)?

Comment: sorry, I wanted to say html, i was thinking of something else. in your html, your element is in a table

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue you've described: I need to click on the arrow of a split button created using extJS in order to display the submenu and then click on one of the menu items that will appear as a result.

The solution that seems to be working is to click on the `td` tag located near by the `em`. 
So the code would be something like this (actually it's a quote of [nillesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503804/nilesh) code with a single change the `td.x-btn-mr` instead of `em.x-btn-split`):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
By findBy = By.cssSelector("tbody.x-btn-icon-small-left td.x-btn-mr");
List<WebElement> elements=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(findBy));
if(elements.size()==2) {
    WebElement element = elements.get(1); //if you want to click first buttons arrow, replace 1 with 0.
    element.click();
}
```